# How can I fetch data from a REST API to a Lex ChatBot (Node.js)

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am an intern working on a chatbot with AWS Lex. I want to be able to tell the bot to "select a file", then "give me the name on the file".

Our company has a REST api containing these files. How would be able to do this?

I cant even get lex to fetch data from **any** API.

If anyone could guide me in the right direction, even fetching data from any public REST APIs, that would help alot! Thank you

> Here is the lambda code that returns "Hello from lambda!" inside the chat window.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    callback(null, {
      "dialogAction": {
        "type": "Close",
        "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
        "message": {
            "contentType": "PlainText",
             "content": "Hello from lambda!"
        }

      }

    });
};
```

Comment: So you want to know how to build your own API?

Comment: You need to give a whole lot more detail. accessing an API is as simple as making a web request using any of the many available http libs. API gateway is for making your lambda function reachable via simple web request.

Comment: You don't really "connect to an API". Rather, some code makes a call to an API, which then returns a response. What do you mean by "our companies internal API"? What does it do? Feel free to edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein edited the question hopefully explained more clearly now!

Comment: @bryan60 edited the question hopefully explained more clearly now!

Comment: not really... you say you can't get Lex to call an API but lex doesn't call API's, it's a chatbot service... lambda can call an API, so why don't you post what you've tried on that front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some resources I would recommend to become more familiar with how to use Amazon Lex:

- YouTube: [(1) AWS re:Invent 2017: Building Multichannel Conversational Interfaces Using Amazon Lex (MCL312) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XGqQP3A-PQ&feature=youtu.be)
- YouTube: [(1) AWS re:Invent 2017: Building a Voice-Enabled Customer Service Chatbot Using Amazon L (MCL301) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TeLvFqLW_0A&feature=youtu.be)
- YouTube: [(1) AWS re:Invent 2017: How I Made My Motorbike Talk, or How to Mix Amazon Lex, Amazon L (ARC331) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55iwsUrCoK4&feature=youtu.be)
- Documentation: [What Is Amazon Lex?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/what-is.html)